# jquery se resizable handle separates

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to resize a textarea in IE in a manner similar to the built in resize in FF and Chrome. So I have applied the jquery ui resizable to the textarea using an se handle. All is good when expanding the textarea. But when reducing the size of the text area somehow the handle gets separated from the corner of the textarea. Like this:-

[image]

I am thinking that perhaps some combination of delay and distance could solve this. But the basic demos don't appear to employ these options and their handles don't get separated. So I am beginning to doubt if I am on the right line. Thus far my tinkering with the options has not been successful.

Any thoughts gratefully received.

Comment: I think that a jsFiddle would help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably NOT the correct answer but it works so I am good for now.

By restricting the expand to the vertical plane only I stopped this behaviour.

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    if ($.browser.msie){
        $("textarea").resizable({
            handles: "se", maxWidth: 465, minWidth: 465, maxHeight: 350, minHeight: 22
        });
    }
});
```

Obviously it is possible to expand in any direction as given in the demos. When a little more time I may review this again.